# Related to Css3 flexbox and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

what is the feature of css3 flexbox and bootstrap.and which one is better like using flex box property or bootstrap grid system?

I am learning more about flexbox so here I got stuck.So please help me out

Comment: Both flexbox and bootstrap are robust approaches to creating responsive designs. Flexbox is native. Bootstrap is a third-party dependency.

Comment: thanks .got it. @Rounin

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is native, while Bootstrap's Grid system is third party. They're both pretty great tools to build a responsive UI.

This blog post is a great rundown of the differences between how they work, and it can help you decide which is best for the type of work you're trying to complete.

https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2018/09/grid-vs-flexbox-which-should-you-choose/

Comment: Careful, CSS Grid is not a third-party library, Bootstrap is, css grid itself is as native as flexbox

Comment: Precisely. This is what I meant to say. Thanks for the catch